# Не вызывается оператор ()

Tags: c++

```
template<class F>
class safecall
{
    F* funcPtr;

public:
    safecall(F* func)
    {
        std::cout << "Contruct" << std::endl;
        funcPtr = func;

        //funcPtr();
    }


    template<class... Args>
    __forceinline decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "call" << std::endl;
        return funcPtr(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

#define SPOOF_CALL(name) (safecall<decltype(name)>(&name));

int main()
{
    (safecall<decltype(Sleep)>(&Sleep))(2000);
    SPOOF_CALL(Sleep)(2000);
}
```

Вывод:

```
Contruct
call
Contruct
```

Почему первый раз оператор `()` вызывается, а второй нет? Макрос же сделает аналогичную запись.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему первый раз оператор () вызывается, а второй нет?

Потому что в коде нет второго вызова.

> Макрос же сделает аналогичную запись.

Нет:

```
#define SPOOF_CALL(name) (safecall<decltype(name)>(&name));
                                                          ^
```

Аналогичный пример:

```
puts("Yes");  // Вызывается
puts;("Yes"); // Не вызывается
```

Comment: Все таки ночью лучше спать)